# Just started new project and when I run npm run dev it throws an error in the terminal

Tags: node.js, vite, esbuild

$ npm run dev

> vite-project@0.0.0 dev
> vite

node:events:346
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: spawn C:\Users\cottamcha\Desktop\Code\portforlio\vite-project\node_modules\esbuild\esbuild.exe ENOENT
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:19)
at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:480:16)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:288:12)
at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:480:16)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21) {
errno: -4058,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'spawn C:\Users\cottamcha\Desktop\Code\portforlio\vite-project\node_modules\esbuild\esbuild.exe',
path: 'C:\Users\cottamcha\Desktop\Code\portforlio\vite-project\node_modules\esbuild\esbuild.exe',
spawnargs: [ '--service=0.11.23', '--ping' ]
}

Answer (score 3):

Try running:
`node ./node_modules/esbuild/install.js`